# Get current value of input HTML JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, input

I have an html page that requires getting the value of an input when a button is pressed so it can be used as a variable in a link. For example, my website would detect "word" being written in the input and would redirect to the link "google.com/word" when the button is clicked. Thanks for any help in advance!

HTML Code:

```
<td><input value="Input text Here..."></input></td>
<td><a href='https://example.com/test/VALUEFROMINPUTHERE'><button id="click">Click this Button</button></a></td>
```

Comment: Its there now I updated the question

Comment: You need to do a bit of research. Find out how to add an event listener, how to read the input value, how to concatenate a string and how to redirect in JavaScript. MDN is a good source for such info. And SO itself often has helpful answers. Also learn how to use your browsers dev tools for debugging. Have a go at writing the JS and if you get stuck put your code in the question with a description of what isn’t working.

Comment: `<input>` is an empty-tag. As such it has no closing tag and `</input>` is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not way to get input value only using HTML... give your button an onclick attribute:

```
<td>
  <a href='https://example.com/test/VALUEFROMINPUTHERE'>
    <button id="click" onclick="click()">Click this Button</button>
  </a>
</td>
```

and your input an ID:

```
<td>
  <input value="Input text Here..." id="input">
</td>
```

and add JS:

```
function click() {
  let val = document.getElementById("input").value
  window.location.href = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + val
}
```

All I'm doing here is geting the input's value, and changing the window's href to the wanted word, also making sure the word is being searched in google by adding the  `"https://www.google.com/search?q="` before adding the value of the input.

Comment: note that you copied the invalid HTML by using `</input>` while `<input>` is an empty tag and has no closing tag!

Comment: Thanks @tacoshy for pointing that out, didn't notice it! fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In this code, when the a tag is clicked, it triggers a JS function that grabs the value of the input with the id "value" and opens thee link with by concatenating it's value to the end of the URL with the window.open() function.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Text" id="value" />
<a href="#" onClick="openLink()">Click Me</a>
<script>
function openLink() {
  let value = document.getElementById("value").value
  window.open(`https://www.example.com/${value}`)
}
</script>
```

Comment: Code only answers are considered low quality. Without sufficient explaination, your answer is hard to understand.
If the OP can't understand your answer, then he also won't be able to reproduce your possible solution. As such it 
would be worthless to him/her. Please add a sufficient explaination of your possible solution.